# Не понимаю почему не сортируются столбцы. C

Tags: c, массивы, структуры, таблицы

Мне нужно отсортировать столбцы по возрастанию, сортировку решил провести методом пузырька, но не понимаю почему значения массива с определенным номером не меняется

```
struct {
    char in[20]; // инвентарный номер товара
    int kolcomp; // количество предприятий, покупающих товар 
    int vol;  // объем продаваемых партий товара каждому предприятию
} product[50];
int n, i, f,
    kv[10];// объем продажи товара всем предприятия
```

...

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    puts("Инвентарный номер(Пример: В120-П): "); gets_s(product[i].in);
    puts("Кол-во предприятий: "); scanf("%d", &product[i].kolcomp); while (getchar() != '\n');
    puts("Объем продаваемых партий: "); scanf("%d", &product[i].vol); while (getchar() != '\n');
    kv[i] = product[i].kolcomp * product[i].vol;
}
```

...

```
int b,c,k;
for (k = 1; k < n; k++)
    for(i = 0; i<n-k;i++)
        if(kv[i] > kv[i+1])
        {
            b = product[i].vol;
            c = product[i].kolcomp;
            product[i].vol = product[i+1].vol;
            product[i].kolcomp = product[i+1].kolcomp;
            product[i+1].vol = b;
            product[i+1].kolcomp = c;
        
        }
puts(title); //вывод таблицы
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("%10s%35d%45d\n", product[i].in, product[i].kolcomp, product[i].vol);
}
```

Получается так:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6E87.jpg
Числа между таблицами это значения kv[i], т.е произведения 2 и 3 столбца, именно по ним идет сравнение

Comment: Вы сравнивает по одному массиву, а меняете другой.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю

Comment: я же через условие "если произведение первых i (2) и (3) столбцов больше I++ (2) и (3) столбцов" начинаю менять значение в каждом i элементе массива столбца (2) и столбца(3), после чего значения меняются между собой, и то что было меньше, по итогу должно подняться вверх.
Если вы про то, что сравниваю я kv[i], а меняю product[i].vol product[i].kolcomp, то тогда если я изменю условие на:
if((product[i].vol * product[i].kolcomp) > (product[i].vol * product[i].kolcomp))
ничего не изменится. Или вы о другом?

Comment: Массив kv не изменяется. А значит Ваши два массива после первого сравнения рассинхронизированы и что получится никто не знает

Comment: Почему он не изменяется? Счётчик же стоит в цикле for на i

Comment: менять надо все данные `kv` и `in` тоже. проще всю структуру копировать по значению `тип_структуры tmp = product[i];`

Comment: По итогу я заменил в условии `kv` на `(product[i].vol * product[i].kolcomp) > (product[i+1].vol * product[i+1].kolcomp))`  И всё заработало. Но всё же для меня так и не дошло почему я не мог оставить там переменную kv, в которой у меня до этого вычислялось произведение.